# Правильно собрать строку в цикле используя присваивание со сложением +=

Tags: javascript

Пытаюсь написать простой код:

(можно скопировать в браузере в консоль и посмотреть результат)

```js
let tpl
for(let i=0; i<10; i++){
    tpl += `
    <p>Строка ${ i }</p>
`
}
console.log(tpl)
```

При использоваении оператора присвоения со сложением первой строчкой выведеться `undefined`, что логично

Додумался только до добавления условия:

```js
let tpl
for(let i=0; i<10; i++){
    if(i==0){
        tpl = `
        <p>Строка ${ i }</p>`
    }else{
        tpl += `
        <p>Строка ${ i }</p>`
    }
}
console.log(tpl)
```

Но мне кажется можно как то проще это сделать, явно лишнее условие. Как правильно сделать это?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё гораздо проще. Надо просто инициализировать переменную начальным значением. В данном случае пустой строкой. Потому что объявление переменной `let tpl` без инициализации - автоматом присваивает переменной значение `undefined`.

```js
let tpl = '';

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    tpl += `<p>Строка ${ i }</p>`
}

console.log(tpl);
```

Comment: То что нужно, так и думал что где то туплю!

Comment: @Greg-- если ответ помог решить проблему - можно ткнуть галочку напротив ответа)

Comment: Так я сразу нажал

Comment: @Greg-- галочку, не стрелочку вверх))

Comment: Понял, исправился